# Option to select Time Zone under Achievements bar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Can we have an option to select desired Time Zone.

[image: UTC Time]

Answer (score 9):

Stack Exchange operates under UTC.

All the timestamps everywhere are UTC and we are not about to change that.

One hopes you already know your local time ;)

Comment: Just a note: chat timestamps are in local time (I'm not sure why: star limits are still based on UTC).